# How to enable "Label every part of multi-features" with pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, labeling

Regarding the 'Label every part of multi-features' check box located in the 'Labels // Rendering // Feature Options' layer properties UI...

Can this be done with pyQGIS?

These two commands enable the labeling, and allow color/font/etc. to work fine.

```
self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
```

Tests with these three commands do not enable multi-feature labels.

```
self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/displayAll", "true")
self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/labelPerPart", "true")
self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/limitNumLabels","false")
```

Comment: `self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/labelPerPart", "true")` should do the trick.

Comment: That command-line doesn't seem to work (see OP examples)

Comment: @GermanCarrillo:  Does the command line mentioned ('labelPerPart'), reflect settings exhibited in the Layer Properties UI?  To confirm that this doesn't function, when opening the layer where said command is applied via pyQgis doesn't have the related box checked ('Label every part of multi-features')...

Comment: Yes, as soon as I run such line, I get the checkbox toggled in the properties dialog. I'm using QGIS 2.14.2, which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: The version which doesn't seem to work is 2.14.3, but I am looking into possible problems with the plugins script which calls on this function.

Comment: Ahh ha, is seems the most likely cause for this problem was a try: statement block full of several other commands. Concerning the except: error was not being expressed by some other trouble spot.  When I moved the command in question after try: block, the solution was found.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo  - Could you please post your answer to this question to receive full credit?

Comment: Done, great that you solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PyQGIS line should do the trick:

```
self.contourLayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/labelPerPart", "true")
```

As soon as you run such line, you should get the 'Label every part of multi-features' checkbox toggled in the properties dialog. I'm using QGIS 2.14.2.

Comment: As a confidant, this posting spawned reanalysis of the original script to reveal a troublesome try: block which faulted prior to the correctly suggested command.  Works great now.  Thanks @GermanCarrillo.